# Excel webservice returning more that 32k characters in a cell

Tags: excel, xml

I am trying to read an `XML` to populate data into a table in excel using `=WEBSERVICE`. But my XML has more than 32k char in it and I am not able to read all the data using `=FILTERXML`.

I tried fetching the XML first using `=WEBSERVICE` and the result has more than 32k in fact it would be 320k.

Is there a way where I can fetch all the data from the excel using `=WEBSERVICE` when the data is huge.

Comment: Would you not load your XML into the worksheet rather than text into a single cell?

Comment: Loading an XML is not an option, should make a webservice call to fetch it

Comment: Yep, so do it in VBA. That’s where my point is headed.

Comment: `WEBSERVICE()` will have the limitations inherent to any Excel function.  Try using `Power Query` aka `Get&Transform`.  You'll be able to extract data also, depending on the xml.